# BlockingIOError when send to non-blocking UNIX soket with SO_SNDBUF

Tags: sockets, unix, blocking, nonblocking

I use nonblocking UNIX UDP socket to transfer data from one process to another:

```
audio_s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
audio_s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 5500000)
audio_s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 5500000)
audio_s.setblocking(0)
try:
    os.remove(SOCKET_PATH)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    pass
audio_s.bind(SOCKET_PATH)
```

And I often send data to remote process:

```
audio_s.sendto(data, REMOTE_SOCKET_PATH)
```

But sometimes (very rare) I catch `BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable` on `sendto` call. What reason can be for this? `Resource temporarily unavailable` looks like very generic sentence.

1. Is it possible to know more detailed information? For example send buffer overflowed of remote receive buffer overflow? Are these possible reasones? or only 1 of them?
2. Can I control current datagram count in send/receive buffer?
3. What is correct way to process or avoid this situation?

If I remove line with:

```
audio_s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 5500000)
```

it works without this exception

Answer (score 2):

Errno 11 is EAGAIN, from 'man sendto':

> [EAGAIN]           The socket is marked non-blocking and the requested operation would block.

Good explanations are there: 
[When a non-blocking send() only transfers partial data, can we assume it would return EWOULDBLOCK the next call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391208/when-a-non-blocking-send-only-transfers-partial-data-can-we-assume-it-would-r)
and there:
[EAGAIN Error: Using Berkeley Socket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989811/eagain-error-using-berkeley-socket-api)